# Concurrent access of records in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am working on finding an elegant solution to handle concurrency conflict in Entity Framework.

My table for administered drugs has a few columns like drug name, dose, frequency, administer method, notes and few more. An operator can modify fields like dose, frequency, administer method etc after reviewing records OR they can just add notes.

SQL Server database is being used by us.

I have added a column `LastUpdated` of type `timestamp`. I'm using this column to raise `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. The `ConcurrencyMode` for the `LastUpdated` column has been set to `Fixed` in the entity designer.

The code snippet from my controller class :

```
// drugId and strNotes are passed from edit screen
DataAccessLayer.Dal dal= new DataAccessLayer.Dal();

// Select record
DrugDetail drugDetail = (from drugRow in dal.DrugDetails
                         where drugRow.id == drugId
                         select drugRow).ToList<DrugDetail>()[0];

// Assign notes 
drugDetail.Notes = strNotes;

try
{
    dal.SaveChanges();
}
catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)dal).ObjectContext.
             Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, drugDetail);

    // Set the notes data again
    drugDetail.Notes = strNotes;

    // Is it possible that DbUpdateConcurrencyException occur again here
    dal.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm worried that concurrency conflict can again occur when `SaveChanges()` is called from catch block. I think it is possible that another user can  modify and save the same record between refresh and save in catch block.

Is my worried valid? I could not find any concrete answer by searching on net.

I was thinking to create this scenario in my test environment and verify behavior but then thought to check in forum here first.

Thanks for help.

As requested DrugDetail class is added here:

```
public partial class DrugDetail
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string DrugName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Dose { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Frequency { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public byte[] LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show the DrugDetail class and the configuration for that (Attribute and/or FluentApi)

Comment: BTW You want SingleOrDefault() or Single() instead of ToList()[0]

Comment: Just an aside: If it is possible that `).ToList<DrugDetail>()[0];` will return null, consider changing that to `).ToList().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @Fabulous Why ToList().FirstOrDefault() and not only FirstOrDefault()? I would use Single() / SingleOrDefault() because that is what you really expect from the query - a single item (or nothing)

Comment: The concurrency conflict can occur between **every** read/write

Comment: @SirRufo - sorry, my mistake. I didn't delete enough characters after pasting the original code. And I had not seen our comment.

Comment: I have added details of DrugDetail class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrency conflict may occur at any time.

Use a loop to repeat the process until you can save the changes without a concurrency conflict.

```
DataAccessLayer.Dal dal= new DataAccessLayer.Dal();

//Select record
DrugDetail drugDetail = (from drugRow in dal.DrugDetails
                         where drugRow.id == drugId
                         select drugRow).Single();

int count = 0;

while ( true )
{
    //Assign notes 
    drugDetail.Notes = strNotes;

    try
    {
        dal.SaveChanges();
        break;
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        count++;
        if ( count > 10 )
          throw;

        ((IObjectContextAdapter)dal).ObjectContext.
                 Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, drugDetail);

    }
}
```

Comment: can move drugDetail.Notes out of loop?

Comment: Good suggestion. I am sure trick to keep SaveChanges() in a loop will enable me to track exception in every attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to homegrow your own optimistic concurrency mechanism. This probably won't work so well because there is always a chance the data has changed, even in the tiny instant between when you call `SaveChanges` and when SQL Server writes the data to the table, while the bits are still going over the wire.

You need special setup in order to make this work correctly. If you are using the Entity Framework, you need to set up the LastUpdated column as the concurrency token, with something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(p => p.LastUpdated).IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Then you'd need to handle any [DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx) thrown during the save operation.

```
bool saveFailed; 
do 
{ 
    saveFailed = false; 
    try 
    { 
        context.SaveChanges(); 
    } 
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) 
    { 
        saveFailed = true; 

        // Get the current entity values and the values in the database 
        var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); 
        var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues; 
        var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues(); 

        // Choose an initial set of resolved values. In this case we 
        // make the default be the values currently in the database. 
        var resolvedValues = databaseValues.Clone(); 

        // Have the user choose what the resolved values should be 
        HaveUserResolveConcurrency(currentValues, databaseValues, resolvedValues); 

        // Update the original values with the database values and 
        // the current values with whatever the user choose. 
        entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues); 
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(resolvedValues); 
    } 
} while (saveFailed);
```

Doing it this way allows the EF to construct the SQL in such a way that the time stamp is checked and the data are updated within the same, atomic transaction.

If you insist on doing it yourself, you could wrap the read and the save in a transaction of your own (be sure to choose an appropriate [transaction isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/transaction-isolation-levels)). However this would be far less efficient and lengthen the time that the row/page/table is locked, which will hurt performance if you have a lot of users.

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: I have defined "Concurrency Mode" = Fixed for LastUpdated field in EDMX diagram. My understanding is that EF will ensure that it doesn't update row in table with old timestamp value of LastUpdated data. I'll read through the list suggested by you. Thanks much for showing me direction.